# How do I resolve this Java Spring: entityManagerFactory Error?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to get my java spring app running, but upon buildung I encounter the following error:

```
Description:

Field productRepository in ch.turwaith.mhd_tracker_backend.ProductController required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
```

The database connection is configured correctly in the application.properties file.
I don't know any further, how can I resolve this? Please tell me what files you need to see in order to understand what the issue is.

Comment: Can you upload your sources to github and send a link?

Comment: Can you check: in productRepository, is there any property named 'entityManagerFactory' and annotated with Autowired? The class of entityManagerFactory is annotated with a corrective annotation by which Spring can understand and instant the class successfully?

Comment: @EvgenyCheryomushkin Sure:
https://github.com/turw41th/mhd_tracker_backend/tree/stackoverflow_question

Answer (score 0):

Please try to recreate your project using spring initializr:

- add web dependency
- add jpa dependency
- add validation dependency
- add mysql driver

2. pom.xml dependencies will look like this:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: It still does not work unfortunately. I guess I will just download a sample project that works for sure from the internet and change it to my needs (in terms of tables and data classes). This is literally the only thing that seems to solve the issue I'm having.

Comment: Your code looks strange. I cant do anything with it to make it work. So I'd suggest to go through tutorial on spring boot. So you will learn how to build spring boot projects. Data classes looks ok. Only problem I see is in structure.